# Curl HTTP Post Issue

Tags: php, curl, post, postman, php-curl

Its Postman HTTP Post request code.

```
POST /upload.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 12.99.22.12
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 79b6cf45-9180-70e1-2136-8af2f8f67271
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="dosya"; filename="deneme--1.csv"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel


            ------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="yukle"

Yükle
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

I written this code. Is it same or not ?

```
 $postfields = array("dosya" => "@$path","yukle"=>"Yükle","filename"=>"deneme--1.csv");
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER , 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        $sonuc=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

The file doesn't uploaded. Why ? The Http code worked but php code doesn't work. I don't know why. where is my mistake ?

Comment: is there any error showing?

Comment: Be specific, "doesn't work" it's not helping you to get an answer. Questions are encouraged to provide a [Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), try to [improve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) yours.

Answer (score 0):

You need create file to upload

```
    // php version >= 5.5
if (function_exists('curl_file_create')) { 
    $file_post = curl_file_create($full_path_file);
} else { 
    $file_post = '@' . realpath($full_path_file);
}
$postfields = array("dosya" => $file_post,"yukle"=>"Yükle","filename"=>"filename");
```